# Failed to determine Pass/Failure of the task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Tags: driver, sign, driver-signing

We have developed driver for printer and preparing its submission for WHQL signature.

We have one failed WHQL test - Failed to determine Pass/Failure of the task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

A link for a test:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj124852.aspx

It is a test of embedded signature - may be it should fail until we drivers are signed?

The logs are below:

```
Failure : Failed to determine Pass/Failure of the task "Run Embedded Signature Test". Task Will be marked as Failed anyway.

Failure : Failed to Parse the LogFile Associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Copying LogFiles From TaskGuidXML "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test"

Cause : Copying File "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" Fails 

Failure : Failed to Copy the Logfiles associated with the Execute Task

Cause : Cannot Find Pattern "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml"

Cause : Failed to Parse the RollupCounts XML file  "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test".

Cause : Failed to move to rool element TaskResult

Cause : the rollup counts XML file  "C:\WLK\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRunFC644A7F-4450-4864-8725-3EBE4E252C47\2773D33C-D67D-440B-94CB-DD76F21788B6.xml" For Task "Run Embedded Signature Test" does not exist.

Cause : The Execute Task with Commandline cmd /c EmbeddedSignature.exe /driver: 2>errorout.txt Failed with ExitCode e0434352
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Russian windows, after installation of English windows version of windows  the problem has been resolved and test passed.

Please close the topic.

Comment: Closing is not appropriate, but you should mark this answer as the right answer by clicking the green checkmark on the left.